How can I use $0 in Makefile?
I would like to include the following command (taken from here) in a Makefile. A simple version of my Makefile script containing the command is:
copy_files:
    sed 's/^/\./' ./input_file | \
        rev | \
        LC_ALL=C sort -u | \
        awk 'p == "" || substr($0,1,length(p)) != p { print $0; p = $0 }' | \
        rev | \
        sed 's/^\.//' > ./output_file

The problem I am having is that when I execute it using make, it fails to recognise the $0 symbol:
awk: cmd. line:1: p == "" || substr(,1,length(p)) != p { print ; p =  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: p == "" || substr(,1,length(p)) != p { print ; p =  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                     ^ syntax error

I tried escaping the $0 using \$0 without success. What is the solution?

Makefiles are already free to use ;)

You were on the right path; to escape the dollar symbol in a Makefile, you need to use $$, not \$:
copy_files:
    sed 's/^/\./' ./input_file | \
        rev | \
        LC_ALL=C sort -u | \
        awk 'p == "" || substr($$0,1,length(p)) != p { print $$0; p = $$0 }' | \
        rev | \
        sed 's/^\.//' > ./output_file

Since you’re constructing an output file using an input file, you should tell Make about this explicitly:
output_file: input_file
    sed 's/^/\./' $< | \
        rev | \
        LC_ALL=C sort -u | \
        awk 'p == "" || substr($$0,1,length(p)) != p { print $$0; p = $$0 }' | \
        rev | \
        sed 's/^\.//' > $@

With this definition, Make will “rebuild” output_file if it is missing or if input_file is newer. $< references the input(s) (known as prerequisites), $@ references the output (known as the target).
If you want a copy_files target, declare that as depending on output_file:
copy_files: output_file

If your Make knows about phony targets, mention that too:
.PHONY: copy_files
copy_files: output_file


Thanks very much. I'm not experienced with Makefiles, I did not even know that "copy_files" had meaning.. Thanks very much.
